# How to add Caching to Opaque Token Introspection

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, token

I am using opaque token introspection, but ideally the tokens should be cached until their expired time (found in one of the claims).

```
@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.
        cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues()).and().
        oauth2ResourceServer()
        .opaqueToken(
        opaqueTokenConfigurer -> {
          opaqueTokenConfigurer.introspectionUri(introspectionUri)
              .introspectionClientCredentials(clientId, clientSecret);
        }).and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
  }
```

I believe I need to create my own OpaqueTokenIntrospector but I can't seem to work out how. I beleive declaring an OpaqueTokenIntrospector bean is supposed to override the default but doesn't seem to work

```
 @Bean
  public OpaqueTokenIntrospector introspector() {
    return new CachingOpaqueTokenIntrospector(introspectionUri, clientId, clientSecret);
  }
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you just need to add opaqueTokenConfigurer.introspector() AFTER the credentials

```
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.
        cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues()).and().
        oauth2ResourceServer()
        .opaqueToken(
        opaqueTokenConfigurer -> {
          opaqueTokenConfigurer.introspectionUri(introspectionUri)
              .introspectionClientCredentials(clientId, clientSecret);
          opaqueTokenConfigurer.introspector(new CachingOpaqueTokenIntrospector(introspectionUri, clientId, clientSecret));
        }).and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
  }
```